# AngularJS: Compile angular code in strings without scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular service that manages all my UI tabs.  It contains an object that has all the information I need about a tab such as icons, labels, URL, etc.  I have a use case for one my tabs to have a dynamic counter on it but I can't figure out how to get it working.

Service snippet:

```
angular.module('app.services').service('tabService', function($rootScope, $route, $location) {

    var tabs = {
        "/front": {
            "search": {
                label: "Search",
                url: "/search",
                classIcon: "fa fa-search",
                urlMatchAddt: ['/searchResults','/productDetails']
            },
            "order": {
                label: "Order",
                url: "/cart",
                classIcon: "fa fa-shopping-bag"
            }  ....
```

HTML Code: index.html (tabService is injected into a my BaseCtrl controller)

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
...
<li ng-repeat="t in tabService.getTabs()" ng-class="{active: tabService.isActiveTab(t.url)}" ng-cloak>
                    <a href="#{{t.url}}"><i class="{{t.classIcon}}" aria-hidden="true" ng-bind-html=""></i>&nbsp;<span ng-bind-html="t.label | trustHTML"></span></a>
                </li>
....
</body>
```

So what I am trying to do for example is in the `label` field of one of my tabs I want to put something like

```
label: "Order - {{counter}}"
```

So every time I update that `{{counter}}` variable then my label will also refresh.  The `label` can also contain HTML code which is why I am using `ng-bind-html` directive.

Currently I am doing an ugly `$watch` on the variable and when it changes then I am manually just completely overwriting the label value with a new string that includes the updated value.

I have tried using `$compile` but I cannot use it with `$rootScope` and I cannot pass `$scope` into my service.  I am unsure what the best solution is.

Any ideas?

**AngularJS**: 1.6

Comment: Is there any problem with doing `<span>{{ t.label }} - {{$index}}</span>`? Why are these creepy ng-bind-html there?

Comment: @estus some of my `label` attributes have html.  Example would be my `counter` will be wrapped in a span tag to utilize a fontawesome icons

Comment: Then please make the question reflect this. Also, there's some template but it's not clear where it is from. Is it a directive? How is it bound with a service? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus updated with extra info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there's a need for a directive/component instead of `<a ...>...</a>`.

There's nothing ugly in `$watch` itself but doing this in one single controller would be certainly ugly.

To calculate strings like `Order - {{counter}}`, `$compile` is total overkill but `$interpolate` service comes to rescue. Its sole purpose is to to what's required, interpolate Angular expressions to strings.

It likely should be something like

```
app.directive('tab', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      tabData: '<',
      counter: '<'
    },
    template: '<a ...>...<span ng-bind-html="interpolatedLabel | trustHTML"></span></a>',
    controller: function ($interpolate, $scope) {
      $scope.$watchGroup(['tabData.label', 'counter'], function () {
        $scope.interpolatedLabel = $interpolate($scope.tabData.label)({
          counter: $scope.counter
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tabService.getTabs()"...>
  <tab tab-data="t" counter="$index"></tab>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work.  Its wrecking havoc with my Boostrap CSS but that's another issue entirely I suppose.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Fixed `</tab>` closing tag in code. You can make it attribute directive like`<span tab ...>` to fit the layout better, but the proper idiomatic way is to make it element directive (basically a component) and provide styling for it, `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.